# Azure Cosmos DB SDK 2, Query a parition key that does not exists without unknow exception?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

When we try to run a query to check if the document exists with a partition key we get a exception.

The code:

```
            var exists = GetQuery(new QueryOptions() { PartitionKey = customer.Id })
                .Where(x => x.Customer.Id == customer.Id && x.Period == period).Select(x => x.Id).Take(1)
                .AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault() != null;
            if (exists)
            {
                //No insert is made.
                return null;
            }
```

> InnerException = {"Message: {"Errors":["An unknown error occurred
> while processing this request. If the issue persists, please contact
> Azure Support: http://aka.ms/azure-support"]}\r\nActivityId:
> 60dae5e2-c542-462f-bcca-640216dac4d7, Request URI:
> /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer11/partitions/a4cb4957-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
> RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2020-07-03T15:20:24.3705569Z,
> RequestEndTime: 2020-07-03T15:20:24.3725571Z,  Number of regions
> attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2020-07-03T15:20:24.3725571Z,
> StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress:
> rntbd://127.0.0.1:10253/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer11/partitions/a4cb4957-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
> LSN: 258197, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid:
> True, StatusCode: 500, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN:
> -1, SessionToken: -1#258197, UsingLocalLSN: True, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Query\r\n, SDK:
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Windows/10.0.18363
> documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.10.0"}

How can i run this code successfully? We are using sdk2.

Comment: Please provide more details. How does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: The rest of the code is only a IQueryable from the documentclient with the request option with the partition key, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

After my testing, the following code hopes to help you.

***Data in my DocumentDB.***

[image]

***Code running result.***

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;

namespace CosmosGettingStartedTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        // <Main>
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning operations...\n");
                DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://localhost:8081/"), "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");

                FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("wuxi") };


                var testQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TestEntity>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("ToDoList", "jason"), queryOptions)
                .Where(f => f.id == "1").Take(1).AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync<TestEntity>()!=null;
                Console.WriteLine(" Check if the document exists: Result is {0}" , testQuery);

                var testQuery2 = client.CreateDocumentQuery<TestEntity>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("ToDoList", "jason"), queryOptions)
                .Where(f => f.id == "1").Take(1).AsDocumentQuery();

                List<TestEntity> retVal = new List<TestEntity>();
                while (testQuery2.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var results = await testQuery2.ExecuteNextAsync<TestEntity>();
                    retVal.AddRange(results);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" Item.id is {0} , Item.address is {1}", retVal[0].id,retVal[0].address);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("End of demo, press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        public class TestEntity : TableEntity
        {
            public TestEntity()
            {
            }

            public TestEntity(string param1, string param2)
            {
                PartitionKey = param1;
                RowKey = param2;
            }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like i got it to work after recreating the collection. I think I had a bug with the emulator, sometimes I got internal server error when I run a simple “where c.id =“ in a query tab